# Drupal: Should I add a view as a field?

Tags: drupal, reference, drupal-7, view, drupal-content-types

I have a view which lists content of type `Bar` based upon content type `Foo` referencing content type `Bar`. When an item of `Foo` is viewed, I'd like to list all the relevant `Bar` items amongst the other fields. How do I use the view (which has a contextual filter of nid) as a field for content type `Foo`? Should I use it as a field (as, it will always be read only as the relationship is built upon `Bar` referencing `Foo` or is there a more "Drupal" way?

I'm thinking a block is inappropriate as I may want to group the view under a tab at some stage

Answer (score 0):

The EVA is exactly what I want (Entity Views Attachment)

https://www.drupal.org/project/eva